# Get array element by key

Tags: arrays, ruby, sinatra

This is my `app.rb`:

```
require 'sinatra'
COMICS = [
  {
    'name' => 'Test #1',
    'code' => 'Link №1'
    },
  {
    'name' => 'Test #2',
    'code' => 'Test №2'
    },
  {
    'name' => 'Test #3',
    'code' => 'Test №3'
    },
  {
    'name' => 'Test #4',
    'code' => 'Test №4'
    }
  ]
get '/' do
  erb :index, :locals => { :comics => COMICS }
end

get '/single/:key' do
  comic = COMICS[params['key']]
  erb :single, :locals => { :comic => comic }
end
```

But when I try accessing: `/single/0` for example I get the following error:

> TypeError at /single/1
>
> no implicit conversion of String into Integer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
comic = COMICS[params['key'].to_i]
```

The param comes from the path so it's a string.